# Equation with limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+...+\sqrt{x^n}}}}=2$

I had never faced with problems like this. Give me, please, a little hint.

Comment: A quick mental-math check says that $3\le x\lt 4$.  Where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: @abiessu I'm getting $x=4$ using a Python program that calculates the $n=100$ term. Also, please note that the answer I posted initially where the answer was $x=\frac 9 4$ was wrong.

Comment: This looks difficult. Evaluating the expression for $x=1$ is easy. But evaluating it for $x=2$ seems much harder - see http://oeis.org/A257576

Comment: @NobleMushtak: oh, you're probably right.  My mental math has proven faulty in the past...  At $n=4$ it's already close to the right value with $x=4$, but not over as in my initial calculation.

Comment: So... we are solving for $x$?

Comment: $x=4$ seems right... but how do we prove it?!

Comment: @abiessu I think it was on some olympiad, now it is in our homework :)

Comment: @NobleMushtak yes, I was so glad when you wrote your first solution, it was so simple!

Comment: @Yuri YOUR HOMEWORK!?  What kind of class you taking?!

Comment: @SimpleArt  I'm the first-year student

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.**
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3+\sqrt{x^4+\ldots}}}} $$
is a continuous and increasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, as well as:
$$ f_k(x) = \sqrt{x^k+\sqrt{x^{k+1}+\sqrt{x^{k+2}+\ldots}}}$$
It is enough to check that $f(4)=3$, or:
$$ f_1(4) = 2\cdot 4^0+1, $$
or:
$$ f_2(4) = f_1(4)^2-4 = (2\cdot 4^0+1)^2-2^2=4+1 $$
or:
$$ f_3(4)=f_2(4)^2-4^2 = (4+1)^2-4^2 = 2\cdot 4+1 $$
or:
$$ f_4(4)=f_3(4)^2-4^3 = (2\cdot 4+1)^2 - 4^3 = 4^2+1 $$
or:
$$ f_5(4)=f_4(4)^2-4^4 = (4^2+1)^2-(4^2)^2 = 2\cdot 4^2+1 $$
$\ldots$ A pattern emerged. Notice that

> $$ f_{2n+1}(4) = 2\cdot 4^n+1 \qquad f_{2n}(4) = 4^n+1 \tag{1}$$

are equivalent, since
$$ f_{2n+2}(x)=f_{2n+1}(x)^2-x^{2n+1}, \qquad f_{2n+1}(x)=f_{2n}(x)^2-x^{2n}. $$

So it is enough to prove that

> $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{f_{2n}(4)}{4^n+1}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{f_{2n+1}(4)}{2\cdot 4^n+1}=1 \tag{2}$$

hold by squeezing.

Comment: Aren't we actually solving for $f_0(x)=2$?

Comment: @SimpleArt: yes, and $f_0$ is increasing, so to prove that the solution is $x=4$ is equivalent to proving my $(1)$.

Comment: How did you know $f_1(4)=3$?  I'd like to see that please.

Comment: @SimpleArt: I don't know that in advance, but $f_0(4)=2$ is equivalent to $f_1(4)=3$, that is my argument.

Comment: XD  Well, I can surely see that.  Then I can assume we are all running on this sort of luck aren't we?

Comment: I don't get what you are saying, but anyway, the point is the following one: we prove $(2)$, we get $(1)$, then we get $f_0(4)=2$, and we are happy.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we have to start somewhere, so we might as well guess and check. I made the following Python program:

```
from math import sqrt
def find_answer(x, n):
    '''Calculates the expression in the limit for given x and n'''
    answer = 0
    for power in range(n, -1, -1):
        answer += x**power
        answer = sqrt(answer)
    return answer

# Here, I guess x from x=2 to x=10 and use n=100 so I am close to the actual limit
for x in range(2, 10):
    print(x, find_answer(x, 100))
```

$x=4$ gives me an answer of $2.0$, so it seems that the answer to this problem is $x=4$, or at least an $x$ very close to $4$.

Answer (score 0):

We are trying to solve for $x$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=2$ and $a_n=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{\dots x^n}}}}$

The trivial possible solutions are $x=0,1$, which do not work.

For $x$

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{\dots x^n}}}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac1x+\sqrt{\frac1{x^4}+\sqrt{\dots x^n}}}}}}$$

$$<\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\dots+1}}}}\tag{If $x>1$}$$

$$=\sqrt{1+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\sqrt{x}}$$

So if we set that equal to $2$, we have

$$x>\left(\frac6{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^2=\frac{27-9\sqrt5}2$$

Comment: I am kind of confused by this answer. How did you get from $2=\sqrt{1+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\sqrt{x}}$ to $\sqrt{x}=5-\sqrt 5$? [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%3Dsqrt(1%2B(1%2Bsqrt(5))%2F2*sqrt(x))) does not agree with your solution. Also, $(5-\sqrt 5)^2=30-10\sqrt 5$.

Comment: Also, wouldn't this be a lower bound on $x$? If $\sqrt{1+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\sqrt{x}}=2$, then $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+[...]}}} < 2$ by your inequality, so we need a greater $x$ in order to make the limit equal $2$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Oh, my mistake.  ;)

Comment: @NobleMushtak And no, its obviously an upper bound.

Comment: How did you get $\left(\frac{6}{1+\sqrt 5}\right)^2=54-18\sqrt 5$? I'm getting $\left(\frac{6}{1+\sqrt 5}\right)^2=\frac{36}{6+2\sqrt 5}=\frac{18}{3+\sqrt 5}=\frac{54-18\sqrt 5}{4}=\frac{27-9\sqrt 5}{2}$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Man, I'm off my game today with small mistakes.  I was close, must've missed a division by two and replaced it with multiplying

Comment: It's OK. We all have those days. :)