# If $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2 +\sqrt{x^3 +\cdots}}}},$ then find the value of $f(4).$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2 +\sqrt{x^3 +\cdots}}}},$ then find the value of $f(4).$

My attempt:
$f(x) = \sqrt{1+{\sqrt{x}} f(x)} \implies f(4) =\sqrt{1+2f(4)} \implies 
f(4)(f(4)-2)=1.$

I don't know how to proceed from here.
The answer should be $2.$ Where am I getting wrong?

Kindly, explain it.Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: Check your third step from $f(4) = \sqrt{1 + 2f(4)}$ to $(f(4) - 3)(f(4) + 1)$ closely again :)

Comment: The first asserted equality $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt x f(x)}$ is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you believe $f(x) = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x} f(x)}$? $xy=1$ does not imply $x=1$ or $y=1$. That only works with zero: $xy=0$ implies $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: @Greg Martin, Would you explain why $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt x f(x)}$ is incorrect?

Comment: @Robert Lee,no sir.

Comment: @Debrogli Multiply $\sqrt{x}f(x)$ and go out to about three or four nested radicals.  It doesn't give the right sequence of exponents.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1785454/1012971

Answer (score 1):

For $y>0$,
\begin{eqnarray}
1+y & = & \sqrt{y^2+(2y+1)}\\
& = & \sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{(2y+1)^2}}\\
& = & \sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{4y^2+(4y+1)}}\\
& = & \sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{4y^2+\sqrt{(4y+1)^2}}}\\
& = & \sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{4y^2+\sqrt{16y^2+(8y+1)}}}\\
& \vdots & \\
& = & \sqrt{y^2+\sqrt{4y^2+\sqrt{4^2y^2+\sqrt{4^3y^2+\sqrt{4^4y^2+\cdots}}}}}
\end{eqnarray}

If you set $y=1$ you get the value of your function for the special case $x=4$, i.e. $f(4)=1+1=2$.

Comment: Note that the relations only hold for $y>0$ as the left hand is 1 for $y=0$ while the limit appears to be 0.